# Serial Communication between Mac OS and RN42 Bluetooth module

Tags: macos, bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, socat

Does anyone know how to establish a serial communication from a Mac OS and a RN42 bluetooth module?

I have connected the RN42 to an Arduino through the UART 3 where I'm expecting to receive what is written in the Mac. I start the module with the Arduino where I send it the "$$$" command that starts command mode and then using the module's commands I establish the connection with de Mac's Bluetooth.

I've already paired the RN42 and the Mac but I can't write in one side and read in the other. I've tried using socat over the files /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port or /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port but it works once in a blue moon.

Hope someone could help me.

Thanks!